# Fill in next blank cell in row - VBA Beginner

Tags: vba, excel

There is a column of values with blank cells in between:

```
20
Blank
30
10
Blank
```

I want to copy this column into a new column in ascending order with the blank cells removed. Then I need to count how many variables are in this new column.

The new column would look like:

```
10
20
30
```

In this case there are 3 variables in the column.

I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Copy and paste the whole column then sort the new column.  Or you can use LARGE() to do it.  Then use COUNT() to count the number of values.

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(A:A,ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

and copy downwards.  In another cell enter:

```
=count(B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your final goal is to get the count then type in below in a cell
    `=COUNTA(A:A)'
You do not need any intermediate steps. This will only count cells with some values